# DSolve gives an empty solution set to a solvable ODE

Tags: differential-equations

I really hope this isn't a duplicate, today I was answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1461098/62278) and was to lazy to solve the quadratic equation on my own and so just asked mathematica to give me the solution of the differential equation, but with the student version of mathematica (9.0.1.0)

`DSolve[{y'[t] == 1/(1 + Abs[y[t]]) , y[4] == 2}, y[t], t]`

and

`DSolve[y'[t] == 1/(1 + Abs[y[t]]) &&  y[4] == 2, y[t], t]`

say that there is no solution to this differential equation (the out is `{}`),
but with Peano (indeed global Picard-Lindelöf is fulfilled) there must be a solution, which indeed can be calculated. Someone in the chat told me that in Mathematica Version 10.1 a solution to this ode is given.

Comment: Solve it without the `Abs[ ]`. If you get a monotonous  increasing function you'll never need the Abs

Comment: @belisarius the ode is autonomous so the solutions are always monotone, here it is monotone increasing but that doesn't help for $t\to -\infty$

Comment: Perhaps instead of of `Abs[y[t]]` you try `Sqrt[y[t]^2]`.

Comment: @chuy I tried it and now I am even more confused, it gives the same wrong answer as maple, and another one which does have a negative derivative which is totally impossible

Comment: Note that this ODE is separable and can be integrated in finite terms (at least if `y` is real).

Answer (score 3):

`DSolve` remaps variables such as `y[t]` to `y` (and derivatives get remapped to `Module` variables and are difficult to access since module numbers change with each invocation), so as long as that does not change, the following will work.

Assume `y` is real:

```
Assuming[y ∈ Reals,
 {dsol} = DSolve[{y'[t] == 1/(1 + Abs[y[t]]), y[4] == 2}, y[t], t]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is a solution and can be used.  To get a more traditional presentation, we can process it further.  First, rewrite the `InverseFunction` solution using the mathematical definition of the inverse function. Then solve for `y[t]`.

```
{invsol} =
 With[{eqn = y[t] == (y[t] /. dsol)},
   Solve[eqn, Cases[eqn, _InverseFunction, Infinity]]
   ] /. HoldPattern[InverseFunction[f_][x_] -> y_] :> f[y] == x

sol = Solve[invsol, y[t], Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Because the right side of `y'[t] == 1/(1 + Abs[y[t]])` is real, if follows that `Im[y[t]]` is constant, and the boundary condition, `y[4] == 2` indicates that the constant is zero.  Thus, `y[t]` must be real.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I realize that, but `DSolve` calls solvers & simplifiers without including that condition.  Or are you adding a justification for why it is ok to include the assumption that `y` is real? Or perhaps some other point I'm unable to see just now?  Or maybe someone deleted a comment you were responding to?

Comment: I was pointing out that your solution was true without "Assume y is real", although you must, nonetheless, tell `DSolve` that it is real for the reason in your last comment.  If you feel that my comment added nothing, I am happy to delete it.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You comment is fine (nice, clear and succinct, too.)  I just wanted to make sure I understood you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Mathematica 10.2.0.0 answer :**

**Method 1:**

```
sol = DSolve[{y'[t] == 1/(1 + Abs[y[t]]), y[4] == 2}, y[t], t]
FullSimplify[y[t] /. sol]
```

[image]

It has problems with the solution of this equation.Simplifying the equations it did not work with FullSimplify[].

**Method 2:**

```
sol2 = DSolve[{y'[t] == 1/(1 + Sqrt[y[t]^2]), y[4] == 2}, y[t], t]
```

> $$\left\{\left\{y(t)\to \sqrt{9-2 t}+1\right\},\left\{y(t)\to \sqrt{2 t+1}-1\right\}\right\}$$

**Maple 2015.1 answer :**

[image]

Answer is:

> $$y(t)=\sqrt{2 t+1}-1$$

Comment: I can't read what is in the box, the maple answer is only a local solution and is wrong for $x\in(-\infty,0)$. Indeed i am more interessted what makes this behaviour than the actual result of the ode

Comment: I can read it now, but the solutions aren't totally correct. And could you tell why it gives these result, and why my version doesn't give them?

Comment: Update your Student Edition to 10.2 and See what happens.Maybe it's a stripped down version.I do not have Student Edition. The results are the result of developers because so programmed.''English translator :P''

Comment: I have 10.2 and it gives the same answer. I guess it's hard for a software to come up with $y(t) = \sqrt{2t+1}-1$ for $t>0$ and $y(t) = 1-\sqrt{1-2t}$ for $t<0$...

Comment: @user58955 well but it could warn you that the result may only be global, it even fails to check it correctly (which is easy because calculating derivatives is easy)

Comment: For Mathematica, it gives the four general functions as Maple does. The thing is that the software fails to glue two pieces together, so after plugging in $y(4)=2$, the negative parts are lost...

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I should clarify that I am pretty sure the student edition is not a stripped down.

Comment: Note that `Sqrt[y[t]^2]` is not the same as `Abs[y[t]]` unless `y` is real.